# Magento2 share only user login on multiple website

Tags: magento, magento2

I am trying to implement common login in multi website for group of sites.
Suppose we have one site which have multicurrency and each website have different payment,price and inventory.

Example : uae.abc.com, in.abc.com, uk.abc.com all website should belongs to abc.com group of websites should have common login, similar would be xyz.com website.

if we tried using **customer scope as global** than once user registered user can login to all sites be it in group or not, trying to fix using below code to access same group using **customer scope as website**.

I have overridden **Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share**

```php
public function isWebsiteScope()
    {
        if(in_array($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(), [1,2,3,4])) {
            return 0;
        }

if(in_array($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(), [5,6,7,8])) {
            return 0;
        }

        return $this->_config->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_SHARE,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        ) == self::SHARE_WEBSITE;
    }
```

But login is not working, can any one help me on this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have single account for all multi-stores you have to do the following:

1 Share customer accounts

You can configure this feature here: System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Share Customer Accounts.

2. Share sessions between Magento websites.

There are 3 possible store configurations:

If your websites are located in one domain, but in different directories, e.g. "www.example.com/stores/store1" and "www.example.com/stores/store2" you can setup your "Cookie Path" to "/stores/" in System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management.

If your websites are located in different sub-domains e.g. "store1.example.com" and "store2.example.com" you can setup "Cookie Domain" to ".example.com" in System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management.

If you have different domains, in this case you can add session ID to the URL for another store. Use this construction "Mage::getModel('core/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('...')" to get the URL with session parameter.

After that your customers will be able to switch between multi-stores Magento websites without re-login. In other words, if customer will login in one Magento website, he will be able to see another multi-store Magento website using his first store account.

Comment: It's for magento 1 need to share same session for limited websites need to magento2

Answer (score 1):

I think that that would be prohibited by either browser Content Security Policy or website XSS prevention. You could try a Microsoft-based sign in system so you could have a user data retrieval from a third database that only allows data to be accessed by the accounts that add it. Then, you also would get all the benefits of Microsoft security.